# Triangulating a partially triangulated mesh (2D)

Tags: algorithm, graph, triangulation

[image]
Referring to the above exhibits, this is the scenario I am working with:

- starting with a planar graph (in my case, a 2D mesh) with a given triangulation, based on a certain criterion, the graph nodes are labeled as RED and BLACK. (**A**)
- a subgraph containing all the RED nodes (with edges between only the directly connected neighbours) is formed (note: although this figure shows a tree forming, it may well happen that the subgraph contain loops) (**B**)

*Problem*: I need to quickly build a triangulation around the subgraph (e.g. as shown in figure **C**), but under the constraint that I have to keep the already present edges in the final result.

*Question*: Is there a fast way of achieving this given a *partially triangulated* mesh? Ideally, the complexity should be in the O(n) class.

Some side-remarks:

- it would be nice for the triangulation algorithm to take into account a certain vertex priority when adding edges (e.g. it should always try to build a "1-ring" structure around the most important nodes first - I can implement iteratively such a routine, but it's O(n^2) ).
- it would also be nice to reflect somehow the "hop distance" when adding edges: add edges first between the nodes that were "closer" to each other given the start topology.

Nevertheless, disregarding the remarks, is there an already known scenario similar to this one where a triangulation is built upon a partially given set of triangles/edges?

Comment: I'm guessing new edges wouldn't be created if they overlap existing edges? Else there would be an edge between the right-most and bottom-most nodes. But, what about creating an edge where a triangle already exists? Like if [2-5-3](http://i.imgur.com/BmKcy33.png) already existed, could we place 2-4-3? (As in, do the we *need* a triangle for every set, or can one take the place of two)

Comment: New edges must not overlap existing ones since this would violate the basic requirements of a valid triangulation. If 2-5-3 already existed, then we would not be able to create 2-4-3 since it introduces an invalid overlapping/folding. Valid triangulations are the only restrictions. The algorithm should stop only if it becomes impossible to create a new triangle and it must not alter existing topology in any way. I will borrow your edited pic for future references if you don't mind :).

Comment: Sure thing, makes it easier to talk about. OK I'll be thinking about this, but I'm sure someone will beat me to an answer. In the meantime, here's a somewhat [related question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32920/algorithm-for-creating-adjacent-triangles).

Comment: I've read the related problem; that algorithm is likely to build a triangle strip, rather than a more complex triangulation (i.e. it will most certainly not build consistent/exhaustive 1-ring neighbourhoods for most vertices in the set).

Comment: All your graph is connected? or it may have multiple sub-graph without connections between them.

Comment: The graph is one single, strongly connected component. It starts out like that, it gets decimated (edges are removed) but it is always connected. The problem is to triangulate it (e.g. Dalunay-like), but using the already present edges and faces as a basis and, preferably, in linear time.

Comment: I have an idea that may help you. I won't take in count that you need speed, just the solution, you can manage to get it faster later (I suppose). First, try to get a convex set of vertices, running a modification to the convex hull algorithm you can get 4 sets (for this example) {1,2,3}, {2,3,4,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,4,5,6} and then, you can run the algorithm to triangulate convex polygons. Now, thinking while posting this comment, you can separate the graph into 3 sets of closed polygons and triangulate each one with a triangulation algorithm.

Comment: When do you consider the result to be finished? When the shape in convex? Moreover, is this 2d or 3d?

Comment: @danijar It is 2D: "starting with a planar graph (in my case, a 2D mesh)"

Comment: @AdrianMaire I had not read careful enough, sorry.

Comment: @nosmirck I also have a solution, but it is iterative, with an unknown number of steps (using a queue and locally adding 1-rings around each node, while pushing the 1-ring vertices that are recently added into that queue). The worst case complexity is obviously not O(n), and it is probably much higher than O(n log n) also. AT danijar I need to stop when I cannot add any other triangle to the mesh (e.g. when you cannot join any two vertices without crossing an already existing edge of the triangulation).

Comment: I tryed an algorithm with aprox O(k*(n log n)) using binary space partitioning but testing it, i realised it fail in some specific cases. I currently does no know any better than O(N^2). If anyone know something better, i am very interested to know solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The only algorithm I've found for solving this problem is the *constrained Delaunay triangulation* algorithm discovered by Paul Chew (http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~plokm/htdocs/cmlab/%B1M%C3D/triangulate/Constrained%20Delaunay%20Triangulations.pdf ).

As in the case of the classical Delaunay triangulation, the complexity is still O(n log n), which is probably reasonable.

I wonder if there is a faster way if one starts with a tree instead of a more general, arbitrary set of non-crossing edges.